# How to create a event that automatically update the status after 10 days?

Tags: mysql

I have sent_date and proposal_status.
suppose sent_date is 23/03/2018 and proposal_status is "Sent/Received".

I wanted to update the status as "Aborted" automatically after 10 days(ie.on 03/04/2018,status should automatically change to Aborted).

What I tried is:

```
CREATE EVENT reset ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 day DO update barter_proposals set proposal_status="Aborted" WHERE DATE_ADD( sent_date, INTERVAL 10 day ) AND proposal_status = "Sent/Received"
```

Temporaily for testing purpose, I have taken minute instead of Day:

```
CREATE EVENT reset ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE DO update barter_proposals set proposal_status="Aborted" WHERE DATE_ADD( sent_date, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE ) AND proposal_status = "Sent/Received"
```

I am getting the result aborted immediately and not after 1 minute. It is ignoring Date_ADD. How to automatically update the status after 10 days?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this expression in your `UPDATE` query.

```
WHERE DATE_ADD( sent_date, INTERVAL 10 day ) AND ...
```

You actually want to compare to the current time, something like this.

```
WHERE DATE_ADD( sent_date, INTERVAL 10 day ) >= NOW() AND ...
```

MySQL has the quirk that when numbers appear in `WHERE` clauses by themselves, they are coerced to Boolean values. Anything nonzero means true. That's why MySQL didn't complain that you are using a `DATETIME` expression without comparing it to anything.

**Pro tip** If you adopt the practice of formatting your SQL so you don't have to scroll around to see it, you'll find it easier to troubleshoot. For example:

```
CREATE EVENT reset ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 day DO 
    update barter_proposals 
       set proposal_status="Aborted"
     WHERE DATE_ADD( sent_date, INTERVAL 10 day ) >= NOW()
       AND proposal_status = "Sent/Received"
```

Note. This event, as you have defined it, will only run every ten days. So some records will be as many as 20 days old before this event changes their status.

Comment: i changed it to that condition but nothing got updated after 1 minutes